# Select id's from Array only if that id exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have two tables :

```
    ____SelectedColors_____
   |___Name___|___Colorid__|
   |   John   |     10     |
   |    Al    |     16     |
       John   |     11


    ______Colors_______
   |___id___|___Color__|
   |   10   |   black  |
   |   22   |    red   |
       11   |   green  |
```

I've also been given an array: (pink, black, purple, green, red )

I want to select those colors in Table Colors, only if they exist in SelectedColors table.

At the moment I have this

```
$sql = "SELECT id
            FROM Colors
            WHERE Color IN (pink, black, purple, green, red )
            GROUP BY id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Color)";
```

I could perhaps do a second query in SelectedColors table and filter them.

However I want to get all done in one go, is it possible?

Select id From Colors where colors in (my array)... only if they exist in the other table...?

Comment: What is the relationship between `SelectedColors` and your ad-hoc list of colors?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SelectedColors.Colorid is an index of Colors.id

Comment: `Select id's from Array only if that id exist in other table` : How about an inner join?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks but I think my question is very clear, I have an array of id's I can select,  however I don't want everything, I want those that are also exist in another column in another table. I want to use only one query.

Comment: I just don't see that there's anything here that could be construed as 'problematic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
SELECT Colors.id FROM Colors
join SelectedColors
on Colors.id = SelectedColors.Colorid
WHERE Colors.Color IN ('pink', 'black', 'purple', 'green', 'red' )
GROUP BY Colors.id
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a group by clause makes no sense, and can return misleading results

Comment: @Strawberry - Here group by just gets unique ids (in case `SelectedColors` table contains  rows with same `Colorid`, there will be duplicates in eventually  result, right?). And because OP used group by in his query, I thought he wants no duplicates, and I used it too.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward query could be:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM Colors AS c
WHERE c.Color IN ('pink','black','purple','green','red')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SelectedColors AS s
              WHERE s.Colorid = c.id)
```

So here we add a constraint that there *exists* a row in `SelectedColors` with a `Colorid` that is equal to the `id` of the color.

This will probably be more efficient than a `GROUP BY` query, since when you `JOIN`, this creates a huge table. A `GROUP BY` thus will scal linear with the number of rows in `SelectedColors`. Here we perhaps only need to inspect a limited number of rows before we find such color.

Comment: This was also helpful thanks for the answer, however I found @oto-shavadze 's code just a bit easier to apply to my code. thanks again